# Setting up android things using an ios device

Tags: ios, android-things

Watched this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkjV-TWLkIc) about setting up an android thing device. But ios devices don't support Nearby Connections so how are we supposed to setup this for ios?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the Android Things Setup Utility from the [console](https://partner.android.com/things/console/#/tools) and still go through the setup, so no need to use an Android Device for that.

[This page](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi) tells you how to do the setup without a phone.